# Como se escribe correctamente esta instruccion para pasar un JSONELEMENT a String

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion que basandome en un fichero JSON que me manden debo generar un listado, pero este fichero va a tener columnas y datos distintos.

Necesito pasar unas lineas por ejemplo que tengo en un JsonElement de seis lineas y las necesito pasara a String para implementar un "Collection" .... la instrución es :

```
String result = gson.toJson(json);
```

El campo "json" es el JsonElement que tiene 6 lineas que corresponde con seis registros , pero el campo "result" solo tiene un solo elemento con todas las 6 lineas del elemento "json", y lo que necesito es que pasen las seis lineas ...
 es decir ..al mirar los datos que me da netbeans .. quiero pasar esto ..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 donde seven quie son seis lineas y cada una contiene una seria de campos...

Esto es lo que deberiasalirme a la hora de Generar un informe JASPER REPORTS con columnas dinamicas .. por el contrario siempre me sales esto ...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que debia aparecerme es estos datos, ojo! esta pantalla esta capturada de otra aplicacion que si funciona ,, soloq estos datos estan sacados de una base de datos y mi problema esta en un fichero Json.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer esto??

Gracias  a todos

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon lo que esperas y lo que recibes actualmente. Ejecutar el código a mi me muestra error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev Es Java, no es ejecutable desde el navegador... edito la pregunta para quitar el "fragmento"

Comment: a Enchev .. gracias lo pondre mas caro ,.. a Pablo .. trabajo con Netbeans

Comment: creo q ahora esta mas explicado .. es leer u fichero Json y pasarlo a jaspèr report... echadme una mano . os lo agradeceria

Comment: Entiendo que quieres pasar al jasper una colección de objetos para generar el informe. Tal como lo tienes planteado no vas a poder hacerlo, no necesitas strings ni nada por el estilo. No te puedo pasar el código pero te doy un enlace donde se hace algo *parecido* y además explican un poco la estructura y la forma de trabajar de **gson** - https://jarroba.com/gson-json-java-ejemplos/. Espero que te sirva